# System.AccessViolationException thrown by OdbcHancle C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, odbc, access-violation

I have an issue with a Application that is replicating stuff between two SQL Server databases.

We get an `AccessViolationException` from time to time. It is not reproducible.

The "source method" can change but all exceptions have the following part of the stacktrace in common:

> System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
>   at System.Data.Common.UnsafeNativeMethods.SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE HandleType, OdbcHandle InputHandle, IntPtr& OutputHandle)
>   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcHandle..ctor(SQL_HANDLE handleType, OdbcHandle parentHandle)
>   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.CreateStatementHandle()
>   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.GetStatementHandle()

The newest ODBC Driver (11) is installed.

**Edit**

Here is the Code of the Method which caused the exception a couple of times:

```
public override int Execute(string sCmd) {
        int nRows = 0;
        m_bError = false;
        m_sCmd = sCmd;
        try {
            OdbcConnection con = OpenConnection();
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sCmd, con);
            nRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            CloseConnection(con);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            f_handleException(e, "Execute", sCmd);
        }
        return nRows;
    }
```

Here the full Stacktrace

```
dummypackage.db.OdbcDatabase.Execute(): System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at System.Data.Common.UnsafeNativeMethods.SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE HandleType, OdbcHandle InputHandle, IntPtr& OutputHandle)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcHandle..ctor(SQL_HANDLE handleType, OdbcHandle parentHandle)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.CreateStatementHandle()
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.GetStatementHandle()
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Prosystem.Toolbox.db.OdbcDatabase.Execute(String sCmd)
    INSERT INTO dummyTable VALUES (1381018,20150422,7343300,4193722002850210,61,1603)
```

Comment: Could you show us some C# code? Probably you are trying to overwrite an unclosed area.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that some of your data values doesnt fit your database schema. For example a column expecting an int is getting a value that exceeds the type int allocation.

Try to log the data when the exception appears and you may get to solve the pb.